# maintain checkbox on dynamically created checkboxes

Tags: php, checkbox, postback

I've searched high and low and can't find an answer to what I'm looking for. I have a list of checkboxes that are created dynamically from a list of categories in a database. Now, what I want to do is to be able to maintain which checkboxes are checked when the page posts back to itself, but nothing i am doing is working =/

```
<?php   
                $mysqli = new mysqli(SERVER_NAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE_NAME);
                if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error()); exit(); }
                $sql = " SELECT TableID AS WebsiteCategoryID, Category FROM listwebsitecategories ORDER BY Category ASC ";
                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->bind_result($selectWebsiteCategoryID, $selectCategory);
                while ($stmt->fetch() == true) :
            ?>
                        <div><input type="checkbox" name="websitecategories[]" id="websitecategories<?php echo($selectWebsiteCategoryID); ?>"<?php if (isset($_POST['websitecategories' . $selectWebsiteCategoryID]) == true) echo(' checked="checked"'); ?> value="<?php echo($selectWebsiteCategoryID); ?>" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo($selectCategory); ?></div>
            <?php
                endwhile;
                $stmt->close();
            ?>
```

I assumed this would work, but it doesn't. I can still retrieve which checkboxes are check by getting an array ($websiteCategories = $_POST['websitecategories']) but maintaining their checked value on postback just won't work.. Please help.

Comment: if your checkboxes are `$_POST['websitecategories']`, why are you trying `isset($_POST['websitecategories' . $selectWebsiteCategoryID])`? Have you tried - `isset($_POST['websitecategories'][$selectWebsiteCategoryID])` where `$selectWebsiteCategoryID` is the array key, not just appended onto the input name?

Comment: If your `$selectWebsiteCategoryID` is the value in the `$_POST['websitecategories']`, not the key, you could change to `if  (in_array($selectWebsiteCategoryID, $_POST['websitecategories'])) == true)`